# Xcode Simulator warning 'Class AVAssetDownloadTask is implemented in both'

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

Since I downloaded the Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B53) from the Apple developer website and opened my project in it I'm getting this error -

> objc[17956]: Class AVAssetDownloadTask is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/watchOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork (0x4149e70) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/watchOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation (0x149f843c). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Im not using anything in my watch app that needs AV or to download anything. How can I resolve this warning?

Thank you.

Comment: checkout link: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/605

Comment: I saw that but I don't use CocoaPods I just have a standard Xcode project.

Comment: checkout this link : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47579

Comment: Its gone now, I noticed Xcode did some downloading of something for watch os 6.1 over the weekend and the error has stopped on its own.